# TYPO3 6.2 typo3_src should be a link

Tags: typo3, mamp, symlink, typo3-6.2.x

I wanna setup a TYPO3 6.2 Installation on MAMP PRO but when I start I get the error:

> /typo3_src should be a link, but it does not exist Links cannot be
>   fixed by this system

So what to do now? Structure is: `Application/MAMP/htdocs/typo3/`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to create symlinks manually, checklist:

1. Open the `terminal`
2. Move downloaded `typo3_src-6.2.4.zip` to host's root

   ```
   mv ~/Downloads/typo3_src-6.2.4.zip /Application/MAMP/htdocs/typo3/
   ```
3. Go to destination folder:

   ```
   cd /Application/MAMP/htdocs/typo3/
   ```
4. **Still in this location**  unzip downloaded package (you can remove zip file after that)

   ```
   unzip typo3_src-6.2.4.zip
   ```
5. **Still in this location** create a symlink to that extracted directory with name `typo3_src` :

   ```
   ln -s typo3_src-6.2.4 typo3_src
   ```
6. **Still in this location** create a symlink to `index.php` pointing file in created symlink:

   ```
   ln -s typo3_src/index.php index.php
   ```
7. **Still in this location** create a symlink to `typo3` folder pointing folder in created symlink:

   ```
   ln -s typo3_src/typo3 typo3
   ```
8. **Still in this location** copy file `_.htaccess` from source folder to host's root:

   ```
   cp typo3_src/_.htaccess ./
   ```
9. **Still in this location** copy file `composer.json` from source folder to host's root:

   ```
   cp typo3_src/composer.json ./
   ```
10. **Still in this location** create file `FIRST_INSTALL`

    ```
    touch FIRST_INSTALL
    ```
11. That's it! Open the host in the browser and start the configuration

After all the steps your file structure should look like (command `ls -la`):

```
FIRST_INSTALL
_.htaccess
composer.json
index.php -> typo3_src/index.php
typo3 -> typo3_src/typo3
typo3_src -> typo3_src-6.2.4
typo3_src-6.2.4
```

**NOTE:** try to avoid using name `typo3` as a folder name for host's root, it's better to use name according to project i.e.: `/Application/MAMP/htdocs/my-project-1/`

Comment: System looks good, thx a lot. Just a little addition, it had to be "/Applications/" instead of "/Application/".

Comment: The idea with symlinks is, that you can replace whole sources to newer version just by replacing one symlink - i.e.: `typo3_src -> typo3_src-6.9.9` ;)

Comment: And you can have multiple TYPO3s using the same source

Comment: **Step 8.1** `mv _.htaccess .htaccess`

Comment: Just migrating from v9 to v10, for this Step 7.1 `ln -s typo3_src/vendor vendor` is missing