# The CSRF protection token for the requested module is missing or invalid in TYPO3 CMS

Tags: typo3

I am a beginner in TYPO3 CMS. I have just installed Typo3 7.4 with following the link [TYPO3 6.2 typo3_src should be a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896319/typo3-6-2-typo3-src-should-be-a-link)

When I try to create pages, it gives me error "The CSRF protection token for the requested module is missing or invalid"

Also there is a message "No pages are found on the rootlevel!" in frontend.

Please help me someone..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:
add new page in the top of the page-tree next the filter icon.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i couldn't use the backend because of the exeption, the only reachable thing was the good InstallTool - which reportet me an outdated mysql version (5.1.x) - TYPO3 7.5.x requires mysql 5.5.x
After yum upgrade mysql the error disappears..