# How to downgrade typo3 7.4.0 to 6.2.15

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, downgrade, typo3-7.x

What are the steps to downgrade a typo3 site and is this even possible?

I cannot get a few plugins to work on my 7.4 typo site so I decided to downgrade but I cannot find anything about it on typo forums or in the documentation. Are there any steps I can follow if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before upgrading your website you should always `backup` your data and avoid `downgrading` at any time.

**Compatibility mode for TYPO3 6.x**

The system extension `compatibility6` is shipped with TYPO3 7, have you tried installing this extension already?

See also: [Retaining compatibility to TYPO3 CMS 6](https://typo3.org/news/article/retaining-compatibility-to-typo3-cms-6/)

**Downgrading from 7.x back to 6.2**

There is no such thing as a documentation with downgrade instructions. But if you have no other option than you can try the following:

*Before running TYPO3 again:*

1. Backup your data
2. Remove the TYPO3 7 core as well the `composer.json` (and `/vendor/` directory), `.htaccess` and `index.php` file from your website.
3. Remove the content of `/typo3temp/`, `/fileadmin/_processed/` and `/fileadmin/_temp_/`.
4. `uninstall` all TYPO3 7 related (system) extensions by setting the `state` to `inactive` in the `/typo3conf/PackagesStates.php` file.
5. Uninstall or downgrade all extensions which are only compatible with `TYPO3 7.x`.
6. Set manual the `['SYS']['compat_version']` in `/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` to `'6.0'` (we let TYPO3 think that we are uograding from `6.0`. Please note that TYPO3 7 doesn't have this option anymore and you need to create it yourself.
7. Remove all array items from the array `['INSTALL']['wizardDone']` in `/typo3conf/PackagesStates.php`.
8. Set manual options such as `['FE']['activateContentAdapter']` back if needed.
9. Put the `TYPO3 6.2` core back in it's place.

*Now you're allowed to run TYPO3 again:*

10. Log in on the `install tool` by accessing `/typo3/install/`.
11. Run the `database compare` but please don't remove `fields` or `tables` that belongs to extensions which you have temporary disabled for downgrading purposes.
12. `Clear all caches` from the install tool.
13. Run al steps from the `upgrade wizard`.
14. Reactivate disabled extensions (manually).
15. Check if the `['SYS']['compat_version']` is set to `'6.2'`.
16. Test your TYPO3 instance as good as you can.

Comment: Yes I have an backup, but I did not want to go through the process of adding files of the backup again. I have to update typo3 4.0 to 6.2, wich will probably not be without any issues. I will try to install the extension my main problem is templavoila not working. thank you for the quick response  I will keep updating my question/progress.

Comment: After installing the compatibilty plugin I came across this issue `Calculated absolute path to typo3/sysext directory does not exist.` would you know what this means?

Comment: I can't support you from here with resolving different issues you'll face when enabling the `compatibility6` extension. Your question is about downgrading from `7.4` to `6.2` and this is my best answer I can give.

Comment: I suppose that is true I shall ask this in another question. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

[Arek van Schaijk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1511943/arek-van-schaijk) solution worked to downgrade 8.7 to 7.6. But a couple of additional changes might require.

1. in the file

> typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/DefaultConfiguration.php

- change `fileCreateMask` from 0664 to 0660
- change `folderCreateMask` from 2775 to 2770

  2. Symbolic links can be rectified with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896319/typo3-6-2-typo3-src-should-be-a-link).

Comment: Whilst my question is over 3 years old, I do appreciate sharing your findings!