# Can I run Typo3 without symlinks?

Tags: typo3

I've installed vagrant on virtual box and now try to install Typo3 but I've no administration rights and can't create symbolic links on my host. Is there the possibiity to install typo3 without symlinks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the instructions from here:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/QuickInstall/GetAndUnpack/Index.html

"Note

Some servers installations do not allow a symlink on a php file, especially on shared hosting environments. Here you should copy the index.php like this:

cp typo3_src/index.php index.php"

Answer (score 1):

You can install Typo3 without symlinks. Just download the .zip file and unpack it on your local computer. Than upload it to your virtual box. You also need an database for it so you need to provide access credentials (user, password and database name. After uploading the files go to yourip/typo3/install and follow the instructions. On Typo3.org there are installation instructions available.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of symlinks:

- We can use TYPO3 source for multiple site
- It is very easy when we need to upgrade TYPO3 version like v7.6.2 to v7.6.5 just we need to change symlinks.

So if you don't have SSH or server access to create symlinks, then you can install without symlinks.
Here example with TYPO3 v7.6.5

- Download .tar.gz or .zip source from [TYPO3.ORG](https://typo3.org/download/)
- Extract and upload folders/files to your root folder "typo3, vendor, index.php, .htaccess"
- Follow installation steps
- Ignore Install Tool Folder Structure error ;)

More: how to symlinks with [mamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896319/typo3-6-2-typo3-src-should-be-a-link#24898724) or in Linux using [windows putty](http://blog.typo3servers.info/show/typo3-symlinks/) 
Thanks to #biesior and #Urs